# how to go back from mount -rw -0 remount / to read only system?

Tags: mount, shutdown

I lost my password so, followed the steps written [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LostPassword) to change my password. After changing the password, i am trying to **reboot** my system by writing **reboot** but it is giving me an error  `shutdown: Unable to shutdown system`

I think that i should remount my disk as read only so, please tell me the command to do so.

Comment: Does it happen also to halt or reboot commands?

Comment: I don't think it has to do with the mounted drives, but it would be `mount -r -o remount /`, I assume. you might also try to run `exit` to get back to the rescue menu. The "resume" command loads the graphical interface (but might be slow) where you can also try to reboot from. `poweroff` should shut it down instead. Did any of those hints help you?

Comment: i just did the power off to shutdown the computer. Thanks for your replies.